# Buttons on Menu page only work in a certain order. (Android Studio - Java)

Tags: java, android

I am very new to AS and Java.

I have a menu page with multiple buttons when I open the app they will only open their activities in the order that my script is in.

I know there is an issue in there somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.
Please go gentle.

```
    public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;
        private Button button3;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.watch);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openWatch();

                }
            });
        }

        public void openWatch() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Watch.class);
            startActivity(intent);



            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openCamera();


                }
                public void openCamera() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Camera.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chart);
                    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            openDistance();

                        }
                    });
                }

                public void openDistance() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Distance.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: You're setting the click listener on button3 after button2 is clicked. Move the method to the outer scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned the onClick to button2 within the openCamera function which is called when button one is pressed. Same for button3. Assign their on clicks outside of the scope of these functions. Should look like this:

```
`public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private Button button3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.watch);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openWatch();

        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openCamera();
        }

    });

     button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openDistance();
                }
            });
}

public void openCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Camera.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openDistance() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Distance.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openWatch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Watch.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}`
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm impressed that my code wasn't as far away as I thought it might!